# How to update ViewPager2 every 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewpager2

I need to keep updating data in Viewpager2
i do it like this,
call every five seconds

```
adapter?.updateData(it)      

fun updateData(items: List<TestDataObject>) {
        list = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

the problem is that the pages display the wrong text after notifyDataSetChange
I think the problem is in notifyDataSetChange, but I don't know how to fix it.

- **full code** [github](https://github.com/shepadoodle/ViewPagerTest)
- **video demonstrating the problem** [photos.google.com](https://photos.app.goo.gl/d5tmqKeXKPYLEP5M6)

MainActivity

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
    import by.lwo.viewpagertest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
    import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
    import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
    
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
        private var adapter: ViewPagerAdapter? = null
        val testList: MutableList<TestDataObject> = emptyList<TestDataObject>().toMutableList()
    
        private val _testLiveData = MutableLiveData<Event<List<TestDataObject>>>()
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            setDataToList()
            setAdapter()
            constantlyUpdateList()
    
            _testLiveData.observeEvent(this) {
                adapter?.updateData(it)
                constantlyUpdateList()
           }
    
        }
    
        private fun constantlyUpdateList() {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                delay(5000)
                setDataToList()
                _testLiveData.value = Event(testList)
            }
        }
    
        private fun setDataToList() {
            testList.clear()
            repeat(6) {
                testList.add(
                    TestDataObject(
                        titleText = "title for page $it",
                        infoText = "infoText for page $it"
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    
        private fun setAdapter(){
            binding.apply {
                adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(testList)
                viewPager.adapter = adapter
                viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = testList.size
            }
        }
    }
```

Adapter

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import by.lwo.viewpagertest.databinding.HolderTestBinding

class ViewPagerAdapter(var list: List<TestDataObject>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.TestHolder>() {

    lateinit var binding: HolderTestBinding

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerAdapter.TestHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.holder_test, parent, false)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)!!
        return TestHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerAdapter.TestHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(list[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    fun updateData(items: List<TestDataObject>) {
        list = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class TestHolder(containerView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView) {
        fun bind(testDataObject: TestDataObject) {
            binding.apply {
                titleTv.text = testDataObject.titleText
                textTv.text = testDataObject.infoText
            }
        }
    }

}

data class TestDataObject(val titleText: String = "", val infoText: String = "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main problems:

1. The `notifyDataSetChanged` method will force you adapter to re-render the whole set of items you have on your activity. It doesn't matter that your list differs from the new one in just one element: it'll get re-rendered in its totality.
   I'd recommend to use `ListAdapter`, which will handle you set for you with the `submitList` method. It is optimized for the use cases where you'll be updating your list very often.
2. And most importantly, the way your adapter is built. You have the property:

`lateinit var binding: HolderTestBinding`

Which is being set in every `onCreateViewHolder` call. However, it is a class field, and every time it is set, the reference of the older holder will be lost and, in every `TestHolder` instance, you'll be referencing the last inflated binding, hence, all of your view holders will be referencing the exact same view holder, instead of their own.
 A better way of doing this is passing the binding to the constructor of every holder:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(...) : ListAdapter(...) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerAdapter.TestHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.holder_test, parent, false)
        val holder = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)?.let {
            TestHolder(it)
        }
        return holder!!
    }

    // 'inner' modifier is not needed
    class TestHolder(private val binding: TestHolderBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(testDataObject: TestDataObject) {
            // this 'binding' will reference their own binding, and not the 'global' one :)
            binding.apply {
                titleTv.text = testDataObject.titleText
                textTv.text = testDataObject.infoText
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813808/11560810)